# Can I sync github issues and milestones with org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, github

Is it possible to effectively use org-mode as a front end to github issues and milestones (with two way sync)?

Comment: Nothing that works well that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be [a fork of `org-sync`](https://github.com/arbox/org-sync) which was last updated in December 2018. It is on [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/org-sync). [Installation](https://github.com/arbox/org-sync):

> ```
> M-x package-install RET org-sync RET
> ```

Add to initialization (.emacs or .emacs.d/init.el)

> ```
> (mapc 'load
>       '("org-sync" "org-sync-bb" "org-sync-github" "org-sync-redmine"))
> ```

Use: In new org-mode-buffer do

> ```
> M-x org-sync-import
> ```

Configure login

> ```
> (setq org-sync-github-auth '("ostesting" . "thisisostesting42"))
> ```

To add issue, create subheading

> ```
> ** OPEN my test issue
> ```

and upload with `M-x org-sync`.

Answer (score 14):

There is a project to allow such functionality, called `org-sync`. (Or rather, `org-sync` has a GitHub backend.) You can find it [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/gsoc2012/student-projects/org-sync/).

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.

The main problem I have noticed is that it doesn't support syncing comments on the issues. As for milestones, it does attach an item to `PROPERTIES` that tells you which one an issue belongs to, but it doesn't look like you can edit milestones directly.